# Magento 2 Setup di Compile Problem

Tags: magento2, command

After I upgraded to Magento 2.3, running the command setup:di:compile, I get this error:

```
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 58 
secs 276.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 35:

  Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist

In ClassReader.php line 29:

   Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist

setup:di:compile
```

I've checked the database setup_module to ensure no mismatch or missing scheme/data versions but all are ok.

Comment: Have you override this class in custom module ?

Comment: Thanks but i have disabled all custom modules so it must have something to do with Magento?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Search for the missing class in your magento2 code, you can do via linux cli:

```
find /path/to/magento2-root -type f -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nw -e 'Magento\\Email\\Model\\Source\\Variables'
```

and comment any line calling this class (that was removed from magento2.3)

**UPDATE**

You can also change this class in Magento 2.3 for `Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables`

Comment: Finally, this solved the problem and i am now able to run setup:di:compile. Thank you!

Comment: How you have fixed?

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :) made my day

Answer (score 2):

I just replaced the class `Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables` with `Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables`.

Answer (score 2):

Class **Bss\HtmlSiteMap\Model\Filter**

```
public function __construct(
    ...  
    \Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables $configVariables,
    ...
)
```

replace

```
public function __construct(
    ...  
    \Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables $configVariables,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dirty Hack**

Rename **registration.php** file of module which is causing problem for compilation.

;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any SMTP extension? If yes then please remove that and then try to run the command :

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If your issue is resolved then install 2.3 compatible SMTP extension.

Comment: I've not used any extensions like this, for further testing i removed env.php and config.php so i can reinstall Magento 2.3, i deselected all modules apart from what Magento needs and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any custom extensions, check the compatibility with Magento 2.3

All extensions that are not compatible must be removed, for example, **Mageplaza smtp** was not compatible and **Mageworx CEO** tool is was also not compatible.

After then run below command: `php bin/magent setup:di:compile`

Comment: Understood, but as per my comments above i have disabled all modules and only left on what Magento needs. Stripped it down and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your generated folder and run the compile command.

```
rm -rf generated/*
```

Then run the compile command

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Thank you, done that plenty of times alongside var/* cache/* etc. No difference.

Comment: Can you check if this class really exists: Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables by going to that path.

Comment: I assume the path is generated/code/Magento/Email/Model - if so, there's no Source directory in there.

Comment: In magento2.2 the class is there, but it looks like this class was removed from magento2.3.

Comment: Check if Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables is being called somewhere in your code

Comment: Thanks gemig_hol for the suggestion, how can i check if it's being called in the code?

Comment: I meant to search in your code for Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables, it shouldn't be there anymore, maybe came wrong from the upgrade

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's the best way to search for that line through all the files? I thought using an FTP client i could but it'll only search for a file name.

Comment: You can use something like this in linux cli grep -rnw '/path/to/magento2-root' -e 'Magento\\Email\\Model\\Source\\Variables' or just search in your ide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87232/discussion-between-gemig-hol-and-mehdi-rafiai).