# Magento 2.4 Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist

Tags: magento2.4

I just upgraded my Magento version to the latest **Magento version 2.4.0**. after a successful upgrade, while I am trying to set production mode I am getting error like

```
    Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/8 [=================>----------]  62% 34 secs 340.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 43:
                                                                      
  Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist  
                                                                      

In ClassReader.php line 36:
                                                                      
  Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist  
                                                                      

setup:di:compile
```

anyone have idea how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be some third-party using these classes in their `di.xml` files and using those classes as well.

In **Magento 2.4**, following deprecated classes were deleted.

```
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\DocumentFactory
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\ScoreBuilder
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\FieldFactory
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder
Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\DataProviderContainer
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\TableMapper
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\ProductFieldset
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Scope\IndexTableNotExistException
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver
```

**Use below command to see the those overrides**

`php bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper"`

Disable/Remove those overrides from the `di.xml` (Any preference/virtual classes/plugin) its self and delete those overrides file as well otherwise whenever `setup:di:compile` runs same error will come.

Check Magento doc as well for other classes and interfaces -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Check your catalog search engine configuration. If it's `mysql`, change to `elasticsearch`

MySQL catalog search engine is deprecated in [Magento 2.4](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043144271-MySQL-catalog-search-engine-will-be-removed-in-Magento-2-4-0)

Comment: its already elasticsearch else site not worked

Comment: If that is the case, this issue is due to third-party modules incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255080/77121

Go in Magento root:

```
 find -type f -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nw -e 'Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Adapter\\Mysql\\Mapper'
```