# Class "Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper" does not exist

Tags: magento2.4.5

After Upgrade Magento latest version problem is showing under custom module.

```
pc-114@pc114-desktop:/var/www/html/gossip$ sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 21 secs 312.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 57:
                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #6 [ <required> Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper ] of Manadev\ProductCollection\Resources\Filters\SearchFilterResource class  
                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:
                                                                        
  Class "Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper" does not exist  
                                                                        

setup:di:compile
```

Comment: this class is delete in magento 2.4. Error comes because you have used this class in di

Comment: php bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper" to see where it is used and remove the class from there

Comment: it's showing

There are no commands defined in the "dev:di" namespace.  
                                                            
  Did you mean this?                                        
      setup:di

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319437/magento-2-4-class-magento-framework-search-adapter-mysql-mapper-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

**Run this command on you root**

```
grep -r "Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper" app/
```

It will show you the file name where you override this class.

Just Disable/Remove those overrides from the `di.xml` **(Any preference/virtual classes/plugin)** and **also delete those overrides PHP file as well** otherwise whenever setup:di:compile runs same error will come.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was caused by Manadev Multiple Select Layered Navigation (Filters) extension, your current extension version is not compatible with Magento 2.4 due to `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper` was removed since Magento 2.4

So, there are some approaches for you:

1. Upgrade Manadev Multiple Select Layered Navigation (Filters) extension to the latest version to check if it resolves your issue.
2. If solution 1 does not work, you have to investigate Manadev extension to fix the issue.
   Hints: Constructor argument Parameter number #6 in `Manadev\ProductCollection\Resources\Filters\SearchFilterResource` class required `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper` but `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper` class does not exist (removed) in Magento 2.4
   Run this command to find the file path of `Manadev\ProductCollection\Resources\Filters\SearchFilterResource` class:
   `grep -r --include \*.php "Magento\\\Framework\\\Search\\\Adapter\\\Mysql\\\Mapper $mapper" app vendor`
3. If you don't have time or do not ready to fix Manadev extension, you should disable it.